# and condition inside or condition mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to query that has and condition inside or condition my query

```
ChatGroup.find({$or:[ {$and : [{'members.user_id':user_id},{'members.is_removed':false} ]}, {'created_by':user_id} ]}]})
```

but it is not giving me desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to use $elementmatch for above query so I get my desired query result